# Reference not updated after install

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, nuget, nuget-package

I have recently upgraded my reference packages
`Microsoft.Aspnet.Mvc`  from 4.0.0 to 5.0.0,
`Newtonsoft.Json` to 6.0.3,
`Microsoft.Aspnet.WebApi` to 5.0.0

And I installed it using NuGet Package Manager Console in Visual Studio 2013. But when I check the version of the references in the solutions explorer, I still see the older version for MVC reference. The other references have been updated.

In the `.csproj` file I see the Reference include for `System.Web.Mvc`  mentions version 4.0.0.0 but HintPath is for 5.0.0.

I tried the following:

1. Deleted the packages directory from Windows explorer
2. Updated package through Package Manager Console, but the problem still persists.

Could someone help me with this?

Edit: Adding one of the reference tags

```
<Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=12345, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>false</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.0.0\lib\net45\System.Web.Mvc.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

As you can see, the Version in the reference is 4.0.0 and that in the hint path is 5.0.0. 4.0.0 is the version I see in the solution explorer.

I also set the specific version tags to `True` for all the references in question and built the code, but again, when I look at the properties of the reference in solution explorer, I see 4.0.0.

Edit 2: I deleted the reference from the solutions explorer, then References >Add References > Browse> Selected the latest downloaded Reference dll from `package` directory. The version in reference manager is 5.0.11001.0

Then I looked at the properties of the added reference. It still is 4.0.0

Comment: The reference should have the flag “Specific version” set to true

Comment: Do I manually have add it or it will automatically take after installing? I followed the same steps installing it in other project and update everything properly.

Comment: Please, share the relevant part of `csproj` file

Comment: @Pavel Added one of the reference tags

Comment: Just remove from this reference the version information, you have to do this manually

Comment: @Dimi I removed the Version=x. Y. Z from the reference tags that should have been updated. Then I built the code, but nothing happened. I also removed the specific version tag and again nothing happened.

Comment: I should also mention that only the Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc reference has not been updated

Comment: Did you change fw target in web.config to .net 4.5?

Comment: @Dimi It was already set to 4.5 before installing new versions